# PhpStorm can not add CLI interpreter

Tags: php, phpstorm

OS: Ubuntu 18.04
PhpStorm: 2019.3

In my project A, I can not add CLI Interpreter, **nothing happens when I click the `...` button** (as image shows).

[image]

However, if I create a new PHP project, this button can be clicked.

Why it happens and how to make the button work normally?

Comment: Please try clicking "..." again and check logs afterwards (Help > Show log in...), is there any error logged?

Comment: @user10550971 the logged msg is "WARN - .PhpRemoteInterpreterComponent - No suitable remote process runner was found 
com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: No suitable remote process runner was found"

Comment: @user10550971 there is a followed error msg "ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Unknown connection type 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown connection type"

Comment: What kind/type of interpreter "php-7.2-debug" is it? Is it a project-specific?

ps. Probably, it will be a nice idea to contact support team via "Help > Contact support".

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue and it drove me insane. I am using version 2020.3.

The log error I was getting was related to the WSL Credential Manager within the IDE:

```
ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Saving invalid credentials
```

It appeared that this error occurred at some point while I was using multiple WSL instances. The Jetbrains IDEs seem to only like a single primary instance installed on the same drive as the OS and IDE.

I found that by opening the IDE and not yet opening a project, you can access the settings, and update the WSL information there.

[image: main ide menu]
[image: wsl settings menu]

Answer (score -1):

I had similiar problem. Here is a solution:

> Looks like this is a problem similar to this [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-237993.).
>   Please exit IDE, open ~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PhpStorm2020.1/Plugins and remove all Docker-in-the-name files and folders. Check if it helps.

Solution provided by: **Dmitry-Tronin from JetBrains**

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)